# In React why does a child component's render function get called twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render

I have the simplest of apps. There's a parent `<App>` component and a child `<MyChildOne>` component. Both are class-based.

Can anyone please explain **why React calls the render function of child `<MyChildOne>`  twice?**

Here's my `<App>` code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import MyChildOne from "./MyChildOne.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyChildOne />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

And here's my `<MyChildOne>` code:

```
import React from "react";

class MyChildOne extends React.Component {
  counter = 0;

  render() {
    this.counter = this.counter + 1;

    console.log(
      "Code has called MyChildOne and this.counter has value: " + this.counter
    );

    return <h1>Hello, {this.counter}</h1>;
  }
}

export default MyChildOne;
```

The output in the browser is this:

**Hello, 1**

And here's what gets logged in the console:

*Code has called MyChildOne and this.counter has value: 1*

*Code has called MyChildOne and this.counter has value: 2*

**So clearly React is calling the render function of `<MyChildOne>` twice – but I cannot understand why!!!!**

This is no good to me because I want to pass as props an array of things from `<App>` to `<MyChildOne>`  and I want `<MyChildOne>` to render, let's say, an `<h1>` for every 'thing' member of that array. I do not want the `<h1>`s to be rendered twice!

Comment: Your code is fine, it called once, perhaps your rendering the common parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dennis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your function is calling child render function a single times only.
2. This is not the approach to create state in class component instead you can use.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        count: 0,
    };
}
```

3. The updation of state should be done using

   **this.setState:**

   **{()=>{this.setState({
   count:this.state.count+1
   })}}**
4. The component that is rendering twice may be because of the event which you might be triggering like I was with my mouse-over event.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't worry too much about the render function being called multiple times. If you're creating logic that depends on the render function being called multiple times, you're most likely doing something wrong. My best would be that you're doing some other logic that causes the render function to being called multiple times.

You should note that if your parent component re-renders, so does your child component. I created a minimal example of the code you provided, which makes it clear that your issue is somewhere else. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-6ud9d

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Stephan :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why but this is only happening in the **strict mode**. I create an [example project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-nmjpj?file=/index.js) with the same code you showed. Try removing the **React.StrictMode** tag in index.js file. You'll see that MyChildOne component is only rendering once.

Also, if you're gonna set a property inside the class and use it inside the **render** method, you should use the **state**. Like this,

```
 state = {
     counter: 0
  }
```

. And Change the **state** like this,

```
this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
```

It'll re-render you component properly.
 But **never** change the state inside of **render** method; it'll break your code.

If you don't want to use the state and lifecycle methods, don't use class components. Use functional components instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, Thet :) I removed the <React.StrictMode> tags and the child component is now rendered only once. It seems very strange that they were causing the double rendering but they were!

Comment: @alienCred In development builds, strict mode deliberately runs some lifecycle methods (including render) an extra time. This is done to expose bugs caused by unsafe use of lifecycle methods. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: My pleasure, alienCred